# Facebook Real Time Update For Subscriptions

Tags: facebook, real-time

I plan on using the real time updates for payment subscriptions for my applications. As each payment comes in each month I wish to give users bonus points towards our game.

I am worried however that if there happens to be a mysql error or some other error while processing the request, the user will not get their coins.

We are using this same system with paypal, however with paypal we have to send specific response message and if we don't paypal will keep sending the real time update. Facebook only requires that the web server responds.

Is there a way in PHP to cause facebook to resend this real time update if I detect a mysql error while processing this update.

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/) on Realtime Updates say:

> If a change notification to your server fails, Facebook will retry again immediately, and then a few times more, with decreasing frequency, over the subsequent 24 hours.

If you hit an exception during processing the data, you can return a failure response to Facebook. Anything 400 and above should work.